# sql запрос и условия

Tags: sql

Имеется sql запрос

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE cvet='#FF0000' AND koks<>'' AND ttf<>'' AND prosmotry>100");
```

и HTML форма, привожу часть:

```
<div><input type="radio" name="koks" value="1"><input type="radio" name="koks" value="2"><input type="radio" name="koks" value="3"><input type="radio" name="koks" value="4"><input type="radio" name="koks" value="5"></div>

<div><input type="radio" name="ttf" value="1"><input type="radio" name="ttf" value="2"><input type="radio" name="ttf" value="3"><input type="radio" name="ttf" value="4"><input type="radio" name="ttf" value="5"></div>
```

Как в sql запрос вставить условие, если например выбран input radio со значение 2 выполнить запрос один, если значение к примеру 3, то другой.

Comment: Прочитайте про sql iif(). Но все же лучше эти условия делать в самом PHP, нежели в запросе.

Comment: Понял, сделаю на php if благодарю.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.